# oracle minus in select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two Tables. A & B

```
ID   Name
1     A
2     B
3     C
4     D
```

and

```
ID   Sal
1    400
2    300
3    500
```

Now I need to fetch the record (both ID, Name) from first table, those sal is not assigned in second table. Using sub query I got this. But i need to solve it without using sub query. 
So I tried with minus operator. But I am getting full first table as it is.

```
select id,name from A
minus
select id,to_char(null) from B;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But without Using Sub Query i need to Solve.

Use this using CTE:

```
with tbl(id) as ( select id from B)
select id,name 
from A 
inner join tbl b
on a.id <> b.id
```

Comment: Thanks, for your valuable reply. I need to know how can we achieve it using 'MINUS'..

Comment: `Minus` clause you cannot use in your case because it works when the two queries you are using having same number of columns and datatype. Check more here about MINUS.https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm

Comment: Thnks for the Link

Answer (score 0):

You can use the minus inside with clause

```
with ids as (
select id
from A
minus
 select id
 from B
 ) select A.id ,A.name 
 from A join ids on ids.userid=A.userid;
```